# How to customize the theme of this syntax highlighter for VSCode (tmlanguage.json)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, tmlanguage

I have a few questions about VSCode Syntax Highlighting tmLanguage.json that I haven't been able to find easily so far in browsing google and the VSCode docs (and textmate docs). All of these apply to [building your own language extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32996211/169992) (I used `yo code` to generate the project). Most of them are about my specific use case.

1. How do you specify custom settings that the user can then override? I would like to specify word wrapping as a togglable option for my script.
2. How do you pick some [scope](https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars) so the colors are what you'd like?
3. How do I get the parentheses to be styled properly?

Here is what I have.

[image]

The styles are:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinring/tmlanguage/master/tmlanguage.json",
  "name": "MyScript",
  "patterns": [
    {
      "include": "#terms"
    },
    {
      "include": "#punctuations"
    },
    {
      "include": "#strings"
    },
    {
      "include": "#numbers"
    }
  ],
  "repository": {
    "terms": {
      "patterns": [
        {
          "name": "entity.name.type.language.myscript",
          "match": "([a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)"
        },
        {
          "name": "entity.name.type.language.parens.myscript",
          "begin": "([a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)\\(",
          "end": "\\)",
          "patterns": [
            {
              "includes": "#terms"
            },
            {
              "includes": "#strings"
            },
            {
              "includes": "#numbers"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "numbers": {
      "patterns": [
        {
          "name": "constant.numeric.integer.myscript",
          "match": "\\b(\\d+)\\b"
        },
        {
          "name": "constant.numeric.decimal.myscript",
          "match": "\\b(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\b"
        }
      ]
    },
    "punctuations": {
      "patterns": [
        {
          "name": "punctuation.separator.parameter.myscript",
          "match": ","
        },
        {
          "name": "punctuation.curly.open.myscript",
          "match": "\\{"
        },
        {
          "name": "punctuation.curly.close.myscript",
          "match": "\\}"
        }
      ]
    },
    "strings": {
      "name": "string.myscript",
      "begin": "\\<",
      "end": "\\>",
      "patterns": [
        {
          "name": "constant.character.escape.myscript",
          "match": "\\\\."
        },
        {
          "name": "punctuation.term.myscript",
          "begin": "\\{",
          "beginCaptures": {
            "0": {
              "name": "meta.brace.curly.myscript"
            }
          },
          "end": "\\}",
          "endCaptures": {
            "0": {
              "name": "meta.brace.curly.myscript"
            }
          },
          "patterns": [
            {
              "include": "#terms"
            },
            {
              "include": "#numbers"
            },
            {
              "include": "#strings"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "scopeName": "source.myscript"
}
```

I got that turquoise color by picking `entity.name.type`, given my default GitHub theme. I don't expect to customize the theme, I just want it to map to a given set of colors within a theme. I would like:

- black for the "entities" (terms)
- blue for the "strings"
- green for the "numbers"
- gray for the punctuation

I have been tinkering for a while trying to get the `<text {term}>` curly brackets to not be red, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Also the parentheses around `another(123)`, they should be gray too.

I am not able to tell how the other languages defined their styles, like JSON (the blue I want):

[image]

Or other JSON:

[image]

The comma in the red should also be gray as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify custom configuration, use [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.configuration) in package.json:

```
"contributes": {
"configurationDefaults": {
  "[markdown]": {
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.quickSuggestions": false
  }
},
```